# When is a row in a record set considered 'very wide'?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, ado.net

I was googling for something unrelated when I happened upon this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647694.aspx

Which gives the following when dealing with Command objects:

"Use CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess for very wide rows or for rows with binary large objects (BLOBs)."

So, when is a row considered to be *very wide*?

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server, a row can only be as wide as the page size minus some overhead-- a maximum of 8060 bytes. The only exception are rows that have out of row storage, i.e. a row with a BLOB in which the row itself only stores a pointer to the actual data.

Therefore, a very wide row would be one near or above about 8000 bytes.